# How to log in using facebook in android app?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

How to authorize facebook sdk? and I after authorization how to get the user detail like name,surname,gender,date of birth, age.

Answer (score 0):

you have to take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

Below code open facebook login dialog and on its listener you can get required data field

```
facebook.authorize(Home.this,permission,new DialogListener() 
                    {
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }

                        public void onError(DialogError e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            try {
                                String str = facebook.request("me");
                                JSONObject jsonObject =  new JSONObject(str);

                                facebookid = jsonObject.getString("id");
                                Log.e("", "facebook id :"+facebookid);

                                fbUserFullName = jsonObject.getString("name");
                                fbUserEmail = jsonObject.getString("email");
                                fbUserGender = jsonObject.getString("gender"); 
                                fbUserBithday = jsonObject.getString("birthday"); 
                     }

                        public void onCancel() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    });
```