# Set date to date picker in android

Tags: android, facebook

I had retrieved Facebook user details to android app as [How to log in using facebook in android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565255/how-to-log-in-using-facebook-in-android-app)".now what i need is the retrieved birthday of user must be set to my date picker in the android app.I searched on Google a lot.but everywhere it mentioned only about setting the current date.I m new to android development.Please help me to solve this.Thanks

Comment: I cna't test it right now, but doesn't public void updateDate (int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) set the date you want on the widget?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#updateDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the init() ; method - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init(int, int, int, android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299392/date-picker-in-android) is the link.I think it will help you.The date retrieved is to be set in the datepicker in the following link.